# How to direct a UDP Packet through a vps tunnel?

Tags: vpn, udp

How to direct a UDP Packet through a VPN Tunnel over a WAN?

Have been trying to set up a instant messenger service though the office network and it dose not have UDP flooding or UDP broadcasting.

Not going through any firewalls, its a message service for just the users inside the network.

Any information or ideas would be wonderful.

Comment: To your first question, UDP datagrams ride inside IP datagrams, so when IP traffic goes through the VPN, UDP automagically goes through the VPN too (unless your routers peek inside the IP datagram to make decisions). If you have IP connectivity to the machines in the office network, you have UDP connectivity as well.

Comment: That's what I've understood from other normal program scenarios.  The issue in this case because the VPNs are on two different subnets, the 'messenger' software talks on UDP 8473 and does not automatically communicate outside of the main subnet (ex: 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.2.0).  The software manufacturer indicates that a "firewall access rule" or UDP Broadcasting must be setup in order for VPN tunnels to automatically send the UDP port 8473 info across multiple subnets, etc.  Someone else made mention of perhaps setting up ROUTE PRINT commands but that would require doing to each PC! THANKS